# Back button title is not visible

Tags: objective-c, ios

Есть `navigationController` с `UICollectionView`. При листании изменяется заголовок контроллера.

Если заголовок длинный, то `back-button` отображается без текста. Проблема в том, что после "длинного заголовка" может быть "короткий", но `back-button` все также отображается без текста. Подскажите, как это можно исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обрезали бы Вы рисунки, а то не удобно смотреть вопрос.

Comment: Обрезал. Не сразу нашел кнопку "править" :)

Comment: Можно попробовать делать self.title = @"...";  в viewDidAppear. Скорей всего вы делаете setTitle один раз при создании  UIViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, можно положить кастомную кнопку в сториборде или в коде

Comment: Не хочется ничего кастомного вводить. В идеале было бы сделать какой-нибудь layoutSubviews...

Comment: можно попробовать во viewDidAppear self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.width = 100;

Comment: похоже, что без кастомных элементов ничего не получится сделать. Спасибо за помощь.